# split a comma-separated values to lines

Tags: hive, hql

In hive i have a table like this

```
  Value   String
  -------------------
  1       [Cleo, Smith]
```

I want to separate the comma delimited string into multiple lines. The number of comma separated values is not fixed.

```
  Value   String
  -------------------
  1       Cleo
  1       Smith
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`lateral view`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) with `explode`.

```
select value,expl_str
from tbl
lateral view explode(split(str_col,',')) t as expl_str
```